# Permission Levels

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-library, sharepoint-list

How to assign Design permission level with following site permissions checked(enabled)-

- Create Subsites
- Manage Web Site

I don't want following site permissions to be enabled(checked) -

- Manage Permissions
- Enumerate Permissions
- View Usage Data

But the site permissions are interlinked. When we enable one site permissions, other permissions get automatically enabled, which are not required.

Answer (score 0):

This is the out of the box behavior which cannot be altered.
When you check `Manage Web Site` permission level, the other permission levels, that the `Manage Web Site` depends upon cannot be unchecked.

What you could do (if you cannot give your users those permissions, but want them to be able to manage your web site) is to write some server side code (web part?) that runs under elevated privileges, which should do only the things that you want them to do, without having the access to other out of the box functionalities for managing web site.